# How to install WordPress alongside Laravel on Nginx with pretty permalinks (SEO-friendly URLs)?

Tags: wordpress, nginx, laravel

I have a Laravel site running on Nginx, and it's fine.

It has a normal folder structure like:

```
/app
/public
/vendor
...
```

The `/public` folder is where the Laravel index.php is.

I've installed WordPress at `/public/blog` because I want my blog to be visible at `mywebsite.org/blog`.

The blog currently works fine if I leave the Permalink Settings defined at `/blog/wp-admin/options-permalink.php` set to "Default" (which means the URLs for posts look like `/blog/?p=123`).  **If I change Permalink Settings to `/blog/%postname%/`, I can't view the posts (I get a Laravel 404 page).**

I definitely want my blog posts to have SEO-friendly URLs (pretty permalinks).

My current Nginx config is:

```
server {
    #This config is based on https://github.com/daylerees/laravel-website-configs/blob/6db24701073dbe34d2d58fea3a3c6b3c0cd5685b/nginx.conf and seemed to be necessary to get Laravel working.
    server_name mysite.local;

     # The location of our project's public directory.
    root F:/code/mysite/public/;

     # Point index to the Laravel front controller.
    index           index.php;

    location / {
        # URLs to attempt, including pretty ones.
        try_files   $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    # Remove trailing slash to please routing system.
    if (!-d $request_filename) {
            rewrite     ^/(.+)/$ /$1 permanent;
    }

    # Yoast WordPress SEO plugin says to add these 2 rewrites:
    rewrite ^/blog/sitemap_index\.xml$ /blog/index.php?sitemap=1 last;
    rewrite ^/blog/([^/]+?)-sitemap([0-9]+)?\.xml$ /blog/index.php?sitemap=$1&sitemap_n=$2 last;

    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9123
    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9123;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~* \.(css|js|gif|jpe?g|png)$ {
        #images, CSS, and JS have 1 week expiration: http://aspyct.org/blog/2012/08/20/setting-up-http-cache-and-gzip-with-nginx/ See also: http://serverfault.com/questions/339240/chromium-audit-says-its-not-caching-static-content-yet-headers-are-set-who-i
        expires 168h;
        add_header Pragma public;
        add_header Cache-Control "public, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate";
    }

}
```

I have spent hours reviewing other answers (listed below) and haven't figured out how to get this working.

Suggestions?

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/10089936/470749
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/18596822/470749
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/17816122/470749
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/12635095/470749
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/11522602/470749
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/6155935/470749
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/23416206/470749
- http://codex.wordpress.org/Nginx#WordPress_Multisite_Subdirectory_rules
- http://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory
- https://rtcamp.com/wordpress-nginx/tutorials/multisite/subdirectories/in-a-subdirectory/

P.S. I'm flexible with where I'd install the WordPress files (e.g. either at `/public/blog` or move it up a level to `/blog` or `/wordpress`).

Comment: hey buddy, answering here to your call to arms :) as discussed on my blog where you posted this link, have you tried moving wordpress up one level and adding a location for it, as described here: http://tom.londondroids.com/2011/11/configuring-nginx-to-serve-multiple-webapps-from-different-directories/ ? cheers

Comment: @gru Thank you so much. Yep, I'd tried that. I think Melvyn's answer below looks good, right?  It seems to work for me!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You route everything to laravel in your `/` location, but you need to write everything `/blog/` to the index.php in `/blog/index.php`:

```
location /blog/ {
    try_files $uri $uri/ @wordpress;
}

location @wordpress {
    rewrite /blog/ /blog/index.php;
}
```

Then your php handler needs path info support:

```
location ^/blog/index.php(/.*)?$ {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(/blog/index.php)(/.*)$;
    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9123;
    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param  PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    include fastcgi_param;
}
```

Turn on debug verbosity for error log if this doesn't work and post log info.

**UPDATE: Note from original question asker:**

Here is a snippet of my new Nginx config, which seems to work for these URLs: /, /blog, /course, /blog/innately-happy, and /blog/sitemap_index.xml

```
...
error_log /Users/myuser/code/myproject/storage/logs/nginx_error.log debug;

 # Point index to the Laravel front controller.
index           index.php;

location /blog/ {
    try_files $uri $uri/ @wordpress;
}

location @wordpress {
    rewrite /blog/ /blog/index.php;
}

location ^/blog/index.php(/.*)?$ {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(/blog/index.php)(/.*)$;
    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param  PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    include fastcgi_params;
}

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
}
...
```

Comment: Thank you! Everything seems to be working!  I think maybe https://github.com/daylerees/laravel-website-configs/blob/6db24701073dbe34d2d58fea3a3c6b3c0cd5685b/nginx.conf wasn't a good idea in the first place; I ended up using https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-install-laravel-with-nginx-on-an-ubuntu-12-04-lts-vps as an example.  I'll see if I can add my `git diff` to your answer so that people can know exactly what I changed to get it to work. Note: remove ` debug` when finished testing and ready to deploy to Production.

Comment: This example worked for me with one major exception. The rewrite wrecks all my css and js references.

Comment: I followed exact same steps but for some reason, when I go to blog folder, I get "Too Many Redirects" error.

Comment: @brs14ku You can restrict the rewrite to only allow what can be put in a slug. Like `rewrite /blog/([a-zA-Z0-9/-]+)$ /blog/index.php/$1`. This assumes you don't allow dots in your slugs and do use an extension (.js/.css) for your resources. Alternatively you can use a look-ahead assertion `/blog/.*(?!wp-includes)$` for the directory where they live (wp-includes I assume).

Comment: Thank you. I think we need to update this "astcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9123;" to "unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;" so that it will work on server.

Comment: @PragneshChaudhari That depends on your fpm config. Example code matches what original author had put in.

Comment: how could we remove /blog from url?

Comment: Thank you so much! After hours of debugging, finally got a solution to work.