# Laravel and WordPress nginx config

Tags: php, wordpress, laravel, nginx, laravel-4

[image]
I would like to have WordPress installed in my Laravel 4 project at /public/cms, I don't need WordPress pages to be accessible through the browser but I do need to Post to WordPress routes to update WP content (forms) from within laravel.

I have tried updating my vhosts file to match with the answer here: [How to install WordPress alongside Laravel on Nginx with pretty permalinks (SEO-friendly URLs)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23645386/how-to-install-wordpress-alongside-laravel-on-nginx-with-pretty-permalinks-seo)

But this is causing a redirect loop.

here is my nginx vhost file:

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name laravel.mylifemysmile.org;
root /var/www/mylifemysmile/public;

    # Point index to the Laravel front controller.
index           index.php;

location /cms/ {
    try_files $uri $uri/ @wordpress;
}

location @wordpress {
    rewrite /cms/ /cms/index.php;
}

location ^/cms/index.php(/.*)?$ {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(/cms/index.php)(/.*)$;
    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param  PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    include fastcgi_params;
}

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$query_string;
}

# Remove trailing slash to please routing system.
if (!-d $request_filename) {
        rewrite     ^/(.+)/$ /$1 permanent;
}

# pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
   # NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini
   # With php5-fpm:
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param                   SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
 }
}
```

**Update**

Here's the new nginx vhost (server block) file:

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name laravel.mylifemysmile.org;
root /var/www/mylifemysmile/public;

    # Point index to the Laravel front controller.
index           index.php;

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$query_string @laravel;
}

# Remove trailing slash to please routing system.
if (!-d $request_filename) {
        rewrite     ^/(.+)/$ /$1 permanent;
}

# pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    set $php_root /var/www/mylifemysmile/public;
    if ($request_uri ~ /cms/) {
        # ok, this line is a bit confusing, be aware
        # that path to /cms/ is already in the request
        # so adding a trailing /cms here will
        # give a "no input file" message
        set $php_root /var/www;
    }
   # NOTE: You should have "cgi.fix_pathinfo = 0;" in php.ini
   # With php5-fpm:
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    include fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param                   SCRIPT_FILENAME $php_root$fastcgi_script_name;
 }
 # now wordpress, remember this lives in a sibling directory of the main app
 location ~ /cms/ {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$args;
    # again, this might look a bit weird,
    # but remember that root directive doesn't drop
    # the request prefix, so /cms is appended at the end
    root /var/www;
    if (!-d $request_filename)
    {
        rewrite ^/(.*)/$ /$1 permanent;
    }
  }
}
```

I moved wordpress out of laravel/public and into its own folder on the same level as laravel. I can now access WordPress content (including images) in the laravel site, but still can't access the wordpress dashboard.

Comment: Is your Wordpress setup configured correctly with the base path and the URL to the site?  Do you know where the redirect loop is occurring?

Comment: The URLs are correct. I can access the login page at /cms/wp-login.php, but a redirect loop occurs if you click log in.

Comment: I just added a screenshot from firebug that sows what the redirect looks like.